# how to make the card stick to top

Tags: html, css, node.js, express, ejs

[SS of webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LN05S.png)

**html (ejs):**
see the part after <%- include("navbar.ejs") -%> inside body tag the ".cardholder" holds "anime-card" which are templates(card.ejs). The first and the last div inside ".cardholder" is same as card.ejs just has different content in h4 tag heading content to *which caused distortion*. please refer the image about to understand it better

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <title>ShinAshchi</title>
</head>

<body>
    <%- include("navbar.ejs") -%>
    <div class="card-holder">
        <div class="anime-card">
            <img class="anime-card-img" src="images/logo.png" alt="404" width="200px" height="200px">
            <div class="anime-heading">
                <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <%- include("card.ejs") -%>
        <%- include("card.ejs") -%>
        <%- include("card.ejs") -%>
        <%- include("card.ejs") -%>
        <%- include("card.ejs") -%>
        <%- include("card.ejs") -%>
        <div class="anime-card">
            <img class="anime-card-img" src="images/logo.png" alt="404" width="200px" height="200px">
            <div class="anime-heading">
                <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur</h4>
            </div>
        </div>

        
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**card.ejs**

```
<div class="anime-card">
    <img class="anime-card-img" src="images/logo.png" alt="404" width="200px" height="200px">
    <div class="anime-heading">
        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis, aspernatur accusantium!</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

**style.css**

```
body{
    line-height: normal;
}
.card-holder
{
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
    /* align-items: center; */
}
.anime-card{
    /* display: flex; */
    /* position: initial; */
    display: inline-block;
    width: 309.800px;
    /* height: 348.8px; */
    height: fit-content;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color:#00FFFF;
    background-image: url("/images/2.jfif");
    /* background-repeat: no-repeat; */
    
}

.anime-card-img{
    /* display:block; */
    padding-top: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
    
}
.anime-heading{
    margin-top: 10px;
    min-height: 100.800px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to your cards, so they all aligned to the top of the row on which they are rendered.

```
.anime-card {
  vertical-align: top;
  /* other styles */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.anime-card{
        /* display: flex; */
        /* position: initial; */
        display: inline-block;
        width: 309.800px;
        /* height: 348.8px; */
        height: fit-content;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding: 20px;
        background-color:#00FFFF;
        background-image: url("/images/2.jfif");
        /* background-repeat: no-repeat; */
        margin-top: 0;
    }
```

Comment: unfortunately didn't worked